# PHP code to get the 1st string of each array value

Tags: php

I am trying to create a program that allows an array, that contains integers and strings, to be passed to the draw_stars() function. When a string is passed, instead of  displaying *, display the first letter of the string according to the example below.

For example:

```
$x = array(4, "Tom", 1, "Michael", 5, 7, "Jimmy Smith");
draw_stars($x) should print the following on the screen/browser:
```

Here's my code so far:

```
$y = array(4, "Tom", 1, "Michael", 5, 7, "Jimmy Smith");
function draw_stars2($ropes){ 
    foreach ($ropes as $rope) {
        echo str_repeat('*', $rope), '<br />'; 
    } 
}

$output2 = draw_stars2($y);
echo $output2;
```

Any idea?

Comment: What's your intended output?

Comment: $x = array(4, "Tom", 1, "Michael", 5, 7, "Jimmy Smith");
    draw_stars($x) should print the following on the screen/browser:

Comment: "draw_stars($x) should print the following on the screen/browser", what's following?

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
$x = array(4, "Tom", 1, "Michael", 5, 7, "Jimmy Smith");

function draw_stars($array){
   foreach($array as $element){
      if(is_int($element)){
        echo str_repeat("*", $element);
      }
      else{
        echo strtolower(str_repeat(substr($element, 0,1), strlen($element)));
      }
      echo "<br>";
  }
}

draw_stars($x);
```

Output:

```
****
ttt
*
mmmmmmm
*****
*******
jjjjjjjjjjj
```

Comment: Oh nice, didn't know about str_repeat

Comment: How to add <br> so that it would return on a new line/

Comment: @Rodel Garcia You just add `echo "<br>";` after `if else` statement.

Comment: @Muhammet I think it's clearer if you echo `<br>` once after if statement.

Comment: question why the letters are caps?

Comment: @RodelGarcia Use `strtolower` function.

Comment: @Muhammet No just once after if-else. There is no possibility for double line breaks.